# segmentation fault on string assignment

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, assign

I have a text file which contains only lines with a message like:

> Hello there
>   howdy

Now I got this function that reads these lines and returns an array containing them.

```
string* printlines(string filename)
{
string line;
int sum = 2;
int i =0;
string *quotes;
ifstream infile(filename.c_str());

quotes= new string[2];

    if (infile.is_open())
    {

      while (infile.good())
      { 
        getline (infile,line);
        quotes[i] = line; // <--- here's the problem
        i++;
       }
    }
infile.close();
return quotes;
}
```

gdb reports that the line in bold has the problem but I don't see it.

Comment: There is very rarely a need to have a function that returns a pointer to a dynamically-created string object.  Just return the string by value.

Comment: Also in a language that uses the star to be pointer dereferencing and multiplication, it is not good to try to bold a line using the star star syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop structure is incorrect and will result in going beyond the end of the array. Even though there are only two lines in the file, no check is immediately after the `getline()` to determine if was successful. The first two lines will be read but eof will not yet be set resulting in a third `getline()` call, going beyond the end of the array.

Change to:

```
while (getline(infile, line) && i < 2)
{
    quotes[i] = line;
    i++;
}
```

Having said that, considering using a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an array:

```
std::vector<std::string> quotes;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    quotes.push_back(line);
}
```

The `std::vector` will dynamically grow to store all read lines. New lines can be added to the text file without any requirement for a code change.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate two strings on the heap if you read more than two lines you're in trouble. If you want to return a dynamically allocated array of strings perhaps use `std::vector` and something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> printlines(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::vector<std::string> quotes;
    std::ifstream infile(filename.c_str());

    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (infile.good())
        {
            std::string line;
            std::getline (infile,line);
            quotes.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    infile.close();

    return quotes;
}
```

This way you don't need to care how many strings are read it will just keep growing making room for all of them and you don't need to worry about memory leaks the vector will delete all the strings when it goes out of scope.